# How to continue the consuming events, if there any errors in the Stream of events from Kafka, without using onErrorContinue

Tags: reactor-kafka

As `onErrorContinue` only works with specific operators.

In our case we used windowing, onErrorContinue doesn't handled error related to Windowing ( Timeout Exception or Overflowexeception).